# why the data sort and recylerview view sort are different

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I wrote a RecyclerView that the item in it can be dragged. When I dragged item moving random. Then I see the data, the order of the data in the adapter and the order of the data showed in the RecyclerView are not same? Why, who can help me?
The code is below:

```
@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    int dragFlag, swipeFlag;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    if (layoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
        dragFlag = ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
        swipeFlag = 0;
    } else {
        dragFlag = ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.UP;
        swipeFlag = ItemTouchHelper.END;
    }
    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlag, swipeFlag);
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    int fromPosi = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    int toPosi = target.getAdapterPosition();
    adapter.move(fromPosi, toPosi);
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventMessage(ModifyMainMenuActivity.class.getSimpleName()));
    return true;
}
```

****and the adapter is followed***

```
public class ShopDecorationAdapter extends 
  BaseRecyclerViewAdapter<ProductListResponse.ProductItem> {

private int imageHeight, imageWidth;

public ShopDecorationAdapter(Context context, int layout, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    super(context, layout, onItemClickListener);
}

public void setImageSize(int imgH, int imgW) {
    this.imageHeight = imgH;
    this.imageWidth = imgW;
}

@Override
protected void bindData(BaseViewHolder holder, ProductListResponse.ProductItem data, int position) {
    holder.getTextView(R.id.tv_product_name).setText(data.name);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams imgLayoutParam = holder.getImageView(R.id.product_icon).getLayoutParams();
    imgLayoutParam.height = imageHeight;
    imgLayoutParam.width = imageWidth;
    holder.getItemView().setLayoutParams(imgLayoutParam);
    holder.getImageView(R.id.product_icon).setLayoutParams(imgLayoutParam);
    if (data.isAddBtn) {
        holder.getTextView(R.id.tv_product_name).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

//            ImgLoadUtils.loadLocalResourceDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.icon_add_in_teaching_record,
//                    holder.getImageView(R.id.product_icon));
            holder.getImageView(R.id.product_icon).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_add_in_teaching_record);
            holder.getTextView(R.id.tv_product_price).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.getTextView(R.id.tv_product_price).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.getTextView(R.id.tv_product_price).setText(mContext.getString(R.string.im_product_price, data.zhimaPrice));
            ImgLoadUtils.loadIntoUseFitWith(mContext, R.drawable.artisan_icon_miss, EncodeUtils.urlString(data.coverPic)
                    , holder.getImageView(R.id.product_icon));
            if (data.isSelected && !data.isAddBtn) {
                holder.getItemView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_cf34270_border1dp_solid_white);

```
        } else {
            holder.getItemView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_white);
        }
    }

}
public void move(int origin, int target) {
        Collections.swap(datas, origin, target);
        if (origin < target) {
            for (int i = origin; i < target; i++) {
                Collections.swap(datas, i, i + 1);
            }
        }
        if (origin > target) {
            for (int i = origin; i > target; i--) {
                Collections.swap(datas, i, i - 1);
            }
        }
        notifyItemMoved(origin, target);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary swap

```
public void move(int origin, int target) {
    //Collections.swap(datas, origin, target);  !!!!!!!!
    if (origin < target) {
        for (int i = origin; i < target; i++) {
            Collections.swap(datas, i, i + 1);
        }
    }
    if (origin > target) {
        for (int i = origin; i > target; i--) {
            Collections.swap(datas, i, i - 1);
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(origin, target);
}
```

Comment: what is the right?when i got the order of the list from adapter with the order showed in the recyclerview is different ,how can i resolve it ?

Comment: ,i add the code. help me ,u doubt the adapter cache?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option.